# objectbox ToMany relation doesn't work in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-objectbox

I'm using *objectbox* in my project, i have `Playlist` entity that include `List of Videos`, i'm using `ToMany` class for the `List<Video> videos` in the `Playlist` entity, it's looks the video is saved successfully but when I pull it back from the *objectbox*, it's doesn't appear.

As you can see in line 154 the video is saved, and in line 156 can't get it back

[image: As you can see in line 154 the video is saved]

[image: And in line 156 can't get it back]

Here's my code:

```
late ObjectBox objectBox;

class ObjectBox {
  late Box<Video> videoBox;
  late Box<Playlist> playlistsBox;

  ObjectBox._create(Store store) {
    this.videoBox = store.box<Video>();
    this.playlistsBox = store.box<Playlist>();
  }

  static Future<ObjectBox> create() async {
    Directory doc = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final store = await openStore(directory: p.join(doc.path, "videos"));
    return ObjectBox._create(store);
  }

  void createPlaylist(String title, Video video) async {
    Playlist playlist = Playlist(title);
    video.playlist.target = playlist;
    playlist.videos.add(video);
    await playlistsBox.put(playlist);
    List<Playlist> list = await playlistsBox.getAll().toList();
    print(list);
  }
}
```

Playlist entity:

```
@Entity()
class Playlist {
  @Id()
  int id = 0;
  @Index()
  final String title;

  @Backlink()
  final List<Video> videos = ToMany<Video>();

  Playlist(this.title);
}
```

Video entity:

```
@Entity()
class Video {
  @Id()
  int id = 0;
  @Index()
  final String videoId;
  final String title;

  final playlist = ToOne<Playlist>();

  Video(this.videoId, this.title);
}
```

Comment: Answered at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/539. Please avoid double-posting, it takes away precious time reading the same thing all over again.